# Integer points in parallelepiped

Tags: abstract-algebra, integer-lattices

There is a parallelepiped in $n$ dimensional vector space over $\mathbb{R}$. All its vertex are integer. Its volume $V>1$. How to prove that there is an integer point which belongs to the parallelepiped but it is not a vertex?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please give some context, in particular, tell us what you've tried so far, including anything in particular you had difficulty with. Also, letting us know where this problem comes from would be helpful. Thanks.

Comment: is the parallelepiped defined by a set of parallel planes or by the vertices?

Comment: By vertices (their coordinates in standard basis)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given a parallelepiped $P$ in $\mathbb R^n$ with all coordinates integers, scale $P$ by a factor of $2$ and centre the result on the origin, giving $Q$. Since $P$ has volume greater than $1$, $Q$ has volume greater than $2^n$. $Q$ is also symmetric about the origin and convex, so [Minkowski's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minkowski%27s_theorem) guarantees at least one interior non-origin point in $Q$ and therefore $P$.

Comment: Why don’t we add extra integer points while “scaling”?

Comment: @Kelly $Q$ is made up of eight copies of $P$. If $Q$ is defined as in the answer, then $P$ has no interior integer points if and only if $Q$'s only interior integer point is the origin.